# Best way to display an array of images to the canvas in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, image, canvas

As the title states, I'm trying to put a series of images into an array and then draw them onto the canvas in HTML5, I'm getting no errors but nothing is showing up. I'm new to HTML5 so am having a bit of trouble.

Here's what I have:

```
    var canvas = document.querySelector('Canvas');

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    function drawImagesToCanvas() {
        var imageArray = new Array();
        imageArray[0] = "graphics/1.png";
        imageArray[1] = "graphics/2.png";
        imageArray[2] = "graphics/3.png";
        imageArray[3] = "graphics/4.png";
        imageArray[4] = "graphics/5.png";
        imageArray[5] = "graphics/6.png";
        imageArray[6] = "graphics/7.png";
        imageArray[7] = "graphics/8.png";
        imageArray[8] = "graphics/9.png";
        imageArray[9] = "graphics/10.png";

        ctx.drawImage(imageArray[0], 120, 280, 220, 150);

    }
```

I thought it may be the file path but I've tried multiple variations.

Comment: Did you read the docs? `drawImage` accepts only few data types as parameters https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: To test the filepath put the path in your URL bar to test, for your current example because the paths don't start with a `/` test the paths like: if the page is `http://example.org/folder1/mypage.html` as `http://example.org/folder1/graphics/1.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't feed a source URL to drawImage; it wants the image itself.  This can be read from a DOM element or by constructing an Image object in code, as shown here:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('Canvas');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawImagesToCanvas() {
  var imageArray = new Array();
  imageArray[0] = "https://placehold.it/220x150";
  // ...

  var img = new Image(); 
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 80, 220, 150);
  };
  img.src = imageArray[0];
}

drawImagesToCanvas();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've swapped the code over and there's still no change. My canvas is blank. Any ideas?

Comment: I changed the code to a functioning snippet, so you can see it working. (Also removed some inadvertently-included ES6 syntax, that may have been the problem. Sorry about that)